# vertical-align:middle problem in ie

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I am working on a project. I am facing a problem in ie. Problem is vertical-align:middle not working for image.If you have any solution for this problem please help me.

Site link:http://dev.tenthtime.com/family/highchairs/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

vertical-align is used for tables not for images. Try using margin and padding if your image is not inside a table.